# `requests_mock` applies to all requests even if they are not set and throws NoMockAddress exception

Tags: python, integration-testing, pytest, pytest-mock, requests-mock

I found that `requests_mock` used as a fixture with `pytest` applies to all requests even if they are not set.

I'm not sure if it's a `requests_mock`/`pytest` bug or I'm missing something. Eventually, I don't need to mock 'api-b' call but I can't find out how to avoid it.

```
def test_reqs(requests_mock):
    requests_mock.get('https://api-a.com/')
    requests.get('https://api-b.com/')
    assert requests.get('https://api-a.com/')
```

I'm writing integration tests using `pytest`, `requests-mock`, and `pytest-mock` for an API endpoint. Under the hood, this endpoint makes several calls to different third party API's that I need to mock.

Some of those calls can be mocked by `requests_mock`.
But some of them can't because they make a call from the inside of a third-party module.

I tried to use `pytest-mock` to mock the last one and found out that it basically doesn't work.
`requests_mock` is still trying to mock that call and throws the next error:
`requests_mock.exceptions.NoMockAddress: No mock address: GET https://api-b.com/`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [`requests-mock` doc](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mocker.html) says, you can achieve this behavior by setting `real_http=True` while initiating the `requests_mock.Mocker()`.

```
with requests_mock.Mocker(real_http=True) as m:
    m.get('http://test.com', text='resp')
    requests.get('http://test.com').text
```

But nothing said of how to use it with `pytest`.
As `pytest` test receives request_mock object as an argument (fixture), you can set it in your test explicitly.

```
def test_reqs(requests_mock):
    requests_mock.real_http = True

    requests_mock.get('https://api-a.com/')
    requests.get('https://google.com/')
    assert requests.get('https://api-a.com/')
```